# Bayesian using PyMC3: PatsyError

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3, pymc

I am trying to use PyMC3 to apply Bayesian linear regression.
I want to predict the Age depending on some measurements.
I found an amazing example and want to apply it with some data.
Below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = data.drop(['User_ID','Gender','Age'], axis = 1)   # the features
Y = data['Age']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

Formula = 'Age ~ ' + ' + '.join(['%s' % variable for variable in X_train.columns[0:]])
print(Formula)

with pm.Model() as normal_model:    
   f = pm.glm.families.Normal()    
   pm.GLM.from_formula(Formula, data = X_train, family = f)   
   normal_trace = pm.sample(draws=2000, chains = 2, tune = 500)
```

When I run it, I got this error

```
PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'Age' is not defined
Age ~ Height + Weight + Duration + Heart_Rate + Body_Temp + Calories
^^^
```

But if I keep the Age in the X, it worked fine, but in this case the Age also involved in the formula which should not be because Age is the dependent variable while the others are the independent variables .
Any idea how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To use the `pm.GLM.from_formula()` method, the DataFrame `data` argument must contain all the variables (predictor and response). A simple way to modify the current code to do this is to reattach the response variable:

```
pm.GLM.from_formula(Formula, data=pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1), family=f)
```

Comment: You can also try Bambi https://github.com/bambinos/bambi, which is a high-level library built on top of PyMC3